# GraphQL vs Elasticsearch what should i use for fast searching performance that return with many different schema?

Tags: elasticsearch, facebook-graph-api, artificial-intelligence, graphql, search-engine

I am making a real-time search that will indicate the correct pattern from the search string. Then it will search with this pattern and return with the correct database schema dynamically.
Example Like: Google Assistant

Comment: This is too general question. I suggest you'll specify what are your requirements - is it a free text search? Are the documents have common schema? Are they large/small docs? 
If you'll put an example of docs and query it would be easier to help. I have a feeling that Elasticsearch might be what you are looking for, but need more info in order to tell.

Comment: Like: Google Assistant but it will use for one specific purpose.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You are comparing apple with orange if you are comparing GraphQL with ElasticSearch. They are totally different technologies.

GraphQL is the API layer technology which compare to REST. It mainly defines the request/response format and structure of your HTTP based API. It is not another NoSQL that help you to store and query data efficiently.

If you are using GraphQL , you still need to query the data by yourself , which the data may actually store and come from NoSQL , SQL DB , ElasticSearch or other web service or blablabla . GraphQL does not care about where you store the data ,the data can even store at multiple data sources. What he cares is that you tell him how to get the data.

Back to your case , you most probably can use ElasticSearch for storing and searching the data efficiently. And put GraphQL in front of ElasticSearch such that users/developers interact with the service through GraphQL API in order to enjoy GraphQL [benefits](https://graphql.org/).

Comment: @KenChan while it's technically true that GraphQL vs ElasticSearch comparison is apples/oranges, the question is still pretty valid. I came here looking for the same. I have Elastic as the backend. For frontend querying, should I use the tools that come with Elastic or should I insert a layer of GraphQL on top of Elastic? That's a fair ask. Your link to benefits is helpful.

Comment: I think calling GraphQL "a NoSQL" sounds like apples and oranges as well...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Use case.

Recently I realized I could have used GraphQL for Searching instead of Elasticsearch (For Just This Use case), with respect to cost of running two services one that GraphQL was reading from and other one is Elasticsearch.

All in all it good you can use these two technologies cause you may need them in different use cases.